# TFAE (A) $(W_1+W_2)\cap W_3=(W_1\cap W_3)+(W_2\cap W_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1,W_2$ and $W_3$ be subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space V. TFAE

(A) $(W_1+W_2)\cap W_3=(W_1\cap W_3)+(W_2\cap W_3)$

(B) $(W_2+W_3)\cap W_1=(W_2\cap W_1)+(W_3\cap W_1)$

(C) $(W_3+W_1)\cap W_2=(W_3\cap W_2)+(W_1\cap W_2)$

Well, I tried to solve this problem by using bases, (Let $e_i$ be a basis of $W_1\cap W_3$ and complete this basis to get  $W_1$'s and $W_3$'s basis etc.) but I couldn't . I feel there can be some approaches to this problem. Could you show me one?

Comment: In all parts, $LHS \supseteq RHS$ is always true; so it's enough to show equivalence of $LHS \subseteq RHS$ in the three statements.  When I worked on a direct proof of (A) $\Rightarrow$ (B), it came out to be a pretty much straightforward proof, starting something like "suppose $x \in W_2$, $y \in W_3$, $x + y \in W_1$; then $y \in W_1 + W_2$ also, so (etc. etc.)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to represent the quotient LHS/RHS ? If possible, we might be able to prove by some symmetricity.